# Ошибка в ответе сервера

Tags: php

Нужно получить данные с другого домена делаю следующим образом, отправляю запрос с соответствующими данными, но в ответе от сервера ошибка, делал все по документации, в чем ошибка?

```
    <?
header('Content-type: json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

$number = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["iv"]));

if (!empty($number)) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = array('a' => 'nis', 'iv' => $number);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://balbalbala.ru/src/ajax2.pl");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($ch);
    echo json_encode($ch);


}

die();
```

Вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все файлы сделайте в кодировке "UTF-8 без BOM".....аа, хотя это bitrix.... там тогда может быть что угодно :D

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос точнее. На скриншоте у вас  json ответа вашего сервера, как я понимаю. Текст ошибки в неправильной кодировке. Попробуйте написать код в два приёма: сперва замените курл какой-нибудь заглушкой (типа `echo json_encode('debug')`); если код отработает нормально, принимайтесь за curl. Обратите внимание, что сериализация (json_encode) ресурса -- это не то что вам, вероятно, нужно. Прочитайте про опцию CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER.

Comment: Кодировку страницы в заголовках укажите. Да и данные пришедшие со стороннего сервера тоже на кодировку проверьте.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Спасибо!